# How to do a print screen or capture an area of the screen

Tags: gnome, screenshot

Is there an equivalent of the Window's <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> + Paste (or better yet the Mac OS <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>) in Gnome?

Comment: For *blackbox* in your `bbkeysrc` (where ever you put that):
`[execute](Print){/usr/bin/maim -i $(xdotool getactivewindow) /home/user/Downloads/$(date "+%Y%M%dT%H%M%S").jpg && beep -l 50 -f 6000}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gnome should have screenshot abilities built already in.

[image: Save screenshot]

However, the default trigger is the <kbd>Print</kbd> key, which your keyboard may lack. You can remap this shortcut with `gnome-keybinding-properties`.

[image: gnome-keybinding-properties]

Comment: By default, "Take a screenshot of a window" is Ctrl-Print. This combination failed to work reliably for me, however, so I changed it.

Comment: Didn't work for me either, thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you use `gnome-screenshot --interactive` you can select the option to select an area instead of the whole screen or window.

Comment: Even better is `gnome-screenshot -a` (which instead of openning the choosing window, goes for select an area immediately). I'm struggling to make this default though.

Comment: This won't capture the contents immediately, though, and [will steal mouse focus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/526115/13308).

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> will do the job. A dialog appears on screen allowing you to select any part of it.

Answer (score 7):

There are tons. I personally use `import`, from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It has the ability to capture the whole screen, a given window, or to let you select an area of the screen and just capture that

#### Specific area

```
$ import /path/to/output.png
```

`import` will let you draw an area with the mouse to capture:

[image: Screenshot of drawing a capture area]

#### Individual window

First you need to find out the X window ID:

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep focus
focus:  window 0x3000006, revert to Parent
```

Then you can run import:

```
$ import -window 0x3000006 /path/to/output.png
```

You can also run `import /path/to/output.png` like when taking a screenshot of a specific area, and when it pauses to let you draw the area with your mouse, click on the target window.

#### Whole screen

Use `root` for the window ID:

```
$ import -window root /path/to/output.png
```

---

You can use [`xbindkeys`](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) to bind those commands to the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key; I use a script called `screenshot`, so my configuration looks like:

```
"screenshot root"
m:0x0 + c:107

"screenshot window"
m:0x8 + c:107
```

Comment: Strangely enough, `xdpyinfo | grep focus` returns a window ID different by a unit by the expected one (found with `wmctrl` and the human knowledge of what window has the focus).

Comment: xdpyinfo | grep focus doesn't work because what if i want to capture other GUI windows instead of current terminal window.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning an alternative to the 'individual window' section: if you type `$ import /path/to/output.png` as in the third example and then click on a window (rather than click+drag to draw an area), then you will get a screenshot of that window.

Comment: @JohnGowers Thanks, didn't know about that

Answer (score 3):

Just wrote this small interface to `xwd`, to make it wait the provided number of seconds before it takes the dump. It seems to work.

```
dumptime () {
  (sleep $1; xwd -root | convert - `date +%I.%M.%S`.png) &
}
```

Also, there are `scrot` and `gnome-screenshot`.

The ImageMagick `import` solution in Mr. Mrozek's answer has a famous "black box" [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=546773) on `-window root` - not everyone gets it, but I do.

According to [this](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Apps/screen-capture.html), `gnome-screenshot` is based on ImageMagick - but it is not a wrapper; I just browsed the code, and it is a big C application.

Answer (score 2):

Hit print screen and if gnome is setup correctly, a screenshot utility will pop up.