# Capture the display contents without stealing mouse focus with Print Screen

Tags: gnome, gnome3, screenshot

In GNOME, when I initiate a Print Screen command, the Print Screen sound and animation will play a couple of milliseconds after I initiate the command, even with `gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot delay` at `0`.

Now, I'm not the type of person to [sit in the drive-thru with a stopwatch](https://www.businessinsider.com/mcdonalds-pledges-1-minute-drive-thru-2014-8), but this delay may cause other problems, namely, that it steals the mouse focus, making it impossible to take a screenshot of the contents of a Drop-down (HTML Select) Control in the browser. This seems to occur regardless of the setting in `gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot include-pointer` (`true` or `false`).

How can I take a screenshot that captures the content of the screen at the time of the command, without altering window focus?