# Command to create a screenshot of a specific area of the desktop

Tags: screenshot

Is there a command which can take a screenshot of a specific *area* of the desktop?

I use Ubuntu. Thanks for every answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a print screen or capture an area of the screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-to-do-a-print-screen-or-capture-an-area-of-the-screen) And https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155352

Comment: Please define "specific".  By absolute pixel co-ordinate, active windows/app, desktop/ work space or full screen?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `import` command.

More information on how to use it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-command-in-linux-with-examples/#:%7E:text=import%20command%20in%20Linux%20system,rectangular%20portion%20of%20the%20screen.)

If the command is not available, you may install the `imagemagick` package to have it.

The usage is like the following:

```bsh
import [options] output-file
```

in which the numerous different `[options]` can be detailed in the man page of import by using `man import`.

Here is an example:

```bsh
import -screen test.png
```

allows you to have a cursor to select a section of your screen and save it in `test.png`

Another example is to save a whole window with its border by doing

```bsh
import -border test2.png
```

Answer (score 2):

On any system using GNOME 3 (which I think includes the current releases of Ubuntu), the built-in screenshot function can take care of this: press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, and you’ll get a selection cursor — drag that over the area you want to capture. The screenshot will be stored in a file in your default “Pictures” directory (the exact name will depend on your settings), and you’ll see it in your list of recently-used documents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a giant fan of [Shutter](https://shutter-project.org/). As you're using Ubuntu, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install shutter
```

You can then change your keyboard shortcuts (delete the existing shortcuts and add new ones) to work with Shutter.

To take a full screenshot, it's:

```
shutter -f
```

To take a screenshot of a specific area:

```
shutter -s
```

Now, why do I prefer it?

First, you can do basic editing with Shutter. You can crop, blur, add arrows, add text, and more. You can also upload (called "Export") directly from within Shutter. Not only does it have a few sites configured, you can also add your own sites to the upload function.

This might be a bit of overkill for some folks, but I find myself using those same features on a regular basis. Shutter is one of those apps that I have sitting in the system tray shortly after booting.